# How to find the max moves using math?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, computer-science

I am designing a game; Here I need to find max score for that I need to find max moves player can make.

for example -

> playerA-value = `abccd` I need to find the substring say `bc` in playerA-value
>
> Now I deleted it. So  playerA-value =  acd
>
> algorithm checks for `bc` and it not found, so max move = 1.

for example -

> playerA-value = `aeerrb` I need to find the substring say `er` in playerA-value
>
> Now I deleted it. So  playerA-value =  `aerb`
>
> algorithm checks for `er` and it found, above steps repeats, finally max move = 2.

**to maximize the score, I can delete it either from the front end of the string or rear end, or combination of both(like first few time front, later check for the back side.**

Is there any formula in combination or permutation to find this?

Comment: Is the game "Start with a string $s$ and a substring $r$, and try to find the maximum number of consecutive removals of $r$ from $s$"?

Comment: yea. right, almost same.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee -please note that,  I can find the consecutive removal of `r` from front side or back side.

Comment: As in, if the substring is `er`, then both `eerr` and `erer` would have max score $2$, right? What about `edr`? Does `edr` have score $0$ or $1$?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee yes to first question, second question - `edr` will have 0

Comment: So you get a point for every valid removal, with removals done sequentially?

Comment: @Sam I am writing a Java method `int maxScore(String bigString, String littleString)` that should find the maximum number of removals of little string from big string ... however, I think that kind of solution is probably more appropriate in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), not really for Math.SE

Comment: @Sam I've written the code, hopefully this works as you intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the following Java code to output the maximum number of removals of a substring from a string.

The code uses `replaceFirst` within a while loop, until it can no longer be applied. The code counts the number of times the while loop executes, and this is the integer output.

```
public class RemoveString {

    public static int maxScore(String bigString, String littleString){
        String tempString = bigString;
        int runningCount = 0;
        while(!(tempString.replaceFirst(littleString, "").equals(tempString))){
            tempString = tempString.replaceFirst(littleString, "");
            runningCount++;
        }
        return runningCount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(maxScore("ababa", "er")); // Should be 0
        System.out.println(maxScore("abaer", "er")); // Should be 1
        System.out.println(maxScore("erababa", "er")); // Should be 1
        System.out.println(maxScore("zzzeraba", "er")); // Should be 1
        System.out.println(maxScore("aerbabaer", "er")); // Should be 2
        System.out.println(maxScore("aeerra", "er")); // Should be 2
        System.out.println(maxScore("aerera", "er")); // Should be 2
        System.out.println(maxScore("aerbera", "er")); //Should be 2
        System.out.println(maxScore("aberebraba", "er")); // Should be 1

    }
}
```

I ran the test code, and all nine test cases gave the expected output.

Comment: this will not work for this case- System.out.println(maxScore("ababaa", "aba")); it should give 2, but your code will print 1.

Comment: You're right! Replacing the first appearance is not always ideal. I think that fact increases the time complexity of the problem. I will try to find a method that actually works when replacing the first appearance does not give the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily solved using BFS.  The following code gives the correct output for all the inputs mentioned above.  I've used JUnit.Assert.assertEquals().

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class RemoveString {
    static class Moves {
        String str ;
        int moves ;
        public Moves(String str, int moves) {
            this.str = str ;
            this.moves = moves ;
        }
    }

    static
    public int maxMoves(String s, String t) {
        int max = 0 ;
        if (s == null || t == null || t.length() > s.length())
            return max ;
        Deque<Moves> q = new LinkedList<>() ;
        q.offer(new Moves(s, 0)) ;
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            for (int sz = q.size() ;  sz > 0 ; -- sz) {
                Moves curMove = q.poll() ;
                max = Math.max(max, curMove.moves) ;
                if (curMove.str.contains(t)) {
                    int nextStart = curMove.str.indexOf(t, 0) ;
                    if (nextStart != -1) {
                        q.offer(new Moves(curMove.str.substring(0, nextStart) + curMove.str.substring(nextStart+t.length()), curMove.moves+1)) ;
                    }
                    int lastStart = curMove.str.lastIndexOf(t, curMove.str.length()) ;
                    if (lastStart != -1) {
                        q.offer(new Moves(curMove.str.substring(0, lastStart) + curMove.str.substring(lastStart+t.length()), curMove.moves+1)) ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return max ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assertEquals(3, maxMoves("babba", "b"));
        assertEquals(2, maxMoves("aabb", "ab"));
        assertEquals(2, maxMoves("ababaa", "aba"));
        assertEquals(1, maxMoves("abaer", "er")); // Should be 1
        assertEquals(1, maxMoves("erababa", "er")); // Should be 1
        assertEquals(1, maxMoves("zzzeraba", "er")); // Should be 1
        assertEquals(2, maxMoves("aerbabaer", "er")); // Should be 2
        assertEquals(2, maxMoves("aeerra", "er")); // Should be 2
        assertEquals(2, maxMoves("aerera", "er")); // Should be 2
        assertEquals(2, maxMoves("aerbera", "er")); //Should be 2
        assertEquals(1, maxMoves("aberebraba", "er")); // Should be 1
    }
}
```